# WordPress: Connecting local WP to a Shared Remote Database with PHP / wp.config

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, shared-hosting

I'm trying to connect my local WordPress build to a remote database I currently host on Bluehost. My account is a shared account; however, I am able to remotely manage the DB on various applications...

I've whitelisted my IP address, and I'm able to remotely connect to that server via Sequel Pro using the SAME credentials that are in my wp-config file; however, when I try to connect via PHP, WordPress is unable to connect and I get a WSOD with no errors in the PHP Log or otherwise...

Using MAMP Pro, ports are using 3306, 443 & 80...

I have the IP address of my database, and my WP config reads as follows (redacted for obvious reasons):

```
define('DB_NAME', 'cpanelusername_dbname');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'cpanelusername_dbusername');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'dbpassword');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'xx.xx.xx.114');
```

Any advice would be helpful.

*edit: debug constant is enabled, no errors shown

Comment: add `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in your wp-config and then check for any errors into the browser

Comment: Already enabled — no errors reporting from the php log, on screen or otherwise...

Answer (score 1):

Resolved. It's helpful to check overriding .htaccess settings as mine was in this case overriding the base url.